# Two rows in Flash Builder DataGrid Header - How?

Tags: flash, datagrid, builder

I have a requirement to change a Datagrid in Flash Builder 4.6 to have two rows in the header.

So for example, instead of a column header looking like this: "Item Qty". I want it to show on two lines in the column header as

"Item"
"Qty"

I guess I would need a HeaderRenderer but not sure how to set it to use two rows instead of one.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a MultiLineCell renderer as described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f4a.html).